# coroutine was never awaited, но все await проставлены. Что может быть не так?

Tags: python, telebot, asyncio

```
import time
from telegram import Bot
import asyncio



chat_id = -****
bot = Bot("*****")


async def  send_random_cat() -> None:
    url = f'****=${time.time()}'
    return await bot.send_photo(chat_id, url)




async def main() -> None:
    return await send_random_cat()
    print('Cat has been sent')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Сначала выводит ошибку:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'send_random_cat()' was never awaited
  send_random_cat()
```

ставлю await

Потом тоже самое, но с main. Тоже ставлю await, теперь он говорит

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'main' was never awaited
  main()
```

Но тут-то куда `await` ставить?

На домашнем ноуте - всё работает без `await`. А при загрузке на сервер - вот эта ошибка.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём дело?

Измененный код

```
import time
from telegram import Bot
import asyncio



chat_id = -**** #замените на свое значение, подробнее ниже
bot = Bot("564****EE")

async def main():
    await send_random_cat()



async def send_random_cat():

    url = f'http***?t=$'
    bot.send_photo(chat_id, url)







if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())





import time
from telegram import Bot
import asyncio


chat_id = -** #замените на свое значение, подробнее ниже
bot = Bot("**")

def main():
    asyncio.run(send_random_cat())


async def send_random_cat():
    url = f'**}'
    await bot.send_photo(chat_id, url)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: Укажите какую именно библиотеку telegram установили, а то их сейчас уже наверное с десяток, и "везде" `import telegram`

Comment: python-telegram-bot

Answer (score 2):

Вы асинхронную функцию `main` пытаетесь вызвать просто как обычную синхронную функцию. Асинхронную функцию нужно вызывать либо с `await` из другой асинхронной функции, либо через `asyncio.run`/`loop.run_until_complete`, либо создавать таск через `asyncio.create_task`, чтобы выполнялось в фоне.

Т.е. в простейшем случае вызов асинхронного `main` должен быть таким:

```
import asyncio


async def main() -> None:
    print("Falling asleep...")
    await asyncio.sleep(1.0)
    print("I slept well")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

См. в документации Python: [Running an asyncio Program](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-runner.html#id1)

По второму варианту кода аналогично - вы вызываете асинхронный метод `bot.send_photo(chat_id, url)` просто как будто он синхронный, он по сути даже не начинает выполняться. Так как он внутри асинхронной функции, нужно добавить `await`:

```
async def send_random_cat():
    url = f'http***?t=$'
    await bot.send_photo(chat_id, url)
```

Comment: Всё так же
async def main():
    await send_random_cat()


async def send_random_cat():
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    url = f'https:/***$'
    bot.send_photo(chat_id, url)

Comment: Ну вы в комментарии сейчас какой-то другой код пишите, причем только фрагмент. Я должен по фрагменту угадать какая в этом коде проблема?

Comment: И то верно, извините
import time
from telegram import Bot
import asyncio



chat_id = -1***
bot = Bot("56***DKEE")

async def main():
    await send_random_cat()



async def send_random_cat():

    url = f'ht***$'
    bot.send_photo(chat_id, url)







if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

Comment: Код добавьте в вопрос

Comment: добавил код, что думаете ?

Comment: @ВладимирФилиппов должно быть `await bot.send_photo(chat_id, url)`, так как `send_photo` - асинхронный метод, и вы вызываете его из асинхронной функции. Прочитайте второе предложение в ответе. В первом варианте кода у вас в этом месте было более правильно.

Comment: @ВладимирФилиппов я дополнил ответ.

Comment: Доброго дня, исправил код. Ошибка, но уже другая . Большая, вот часть During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Может быть дело в сервере на котором стоит бот ?
Добавил скрин ошибки

Comment: @ВладимирФилиппов задайте отдельный вопрос по этой проблеме.